# What would be harder to stop: A metal barrel or a wooden one given same rpm?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

When given time and angular retardation we can find the angle moved right?

My question is wont this differ from object to object since moment of inertia comes into play?

so wont it be actually be harder to stop a metal barrel with the same angular retardation?

Comment: It has nothing to do with wood or metal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems like you understand.

A metal barrel the same size as a wooden one would be harder to stop given the same RPM.  The metal would have higher rotational inertia, due to the moment of inertia of the metal barrel being higher due to metal's larger mass, so it would require greater angular retardation to stop the rotation.

If it were also moving (say rolling down a slope), the metal barrel would also have greater linear momentum that the wooden one, making the metal barrel even harder to stop in comparison.

Comment: okay just to make sure ,since torque is L.alpha greater the L greater the force required to stop it?

Comment: @zeitviator Yes, basically.  Since torque on a body determines it's change in angular momentum (L) over time, and the metal barrel has a higher L, you would need to apply more torque in the same amount of time to stop the metal barrel compared to the wooden one; or just apply the same torque over more time to stop the metal barrel.

Comment: what about an oak barrel versus a basswood barrel? Neither you nor OP have said anything about mass! It's not material, it's mass.

Comment: @BillN True, neither of us actually said the m word; but I kinda just assumed OP was aware that was why it had greater inertia.  I'll add the word in to be more explicit.